# Refreshing any page with Google Maps API crashes IE8

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

For the past couple of days we've been experiencing problems with web pages using Google Maps API V3.

Originally I thought it was one particular page on our website, and have spent at least a day trying to find the cause.
This morning I found it was any page with a map on our website, and have just found it's any page on any website with a map.

We are using IE8 on Windows XP, the problem is that on a page with a map is refreshed IE8 crashes.
If "Enable automatic crash recovery" is on in Internet Options/Advanced then you'll get a "balloon" error:
**This tab has been recovered
A problem with this webpage cause Internet Explorer to close and reopen the tab.**

If "Enable automatic crash recovery" is off, the usual **"Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close"** message box appears, but clicking Debug just closes IE.

This happens on the simple example page from Google, it will load fine, press F5 and IE will crash.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

**This only happens on IE8 on Windows XP.**  IE7 on XP and IE9 on Windows 7 are fine, as are Firefox and Chrome.

Can anyone else confirm this, and have any idea how to resolve?

Thanks,
Mike

**Update:
Have found that it works fine if XP is started in Safe mode with Networking**

Comment: Google moved technical support for the Maps API V3 from their own Google Groups to Stack Overflow some time ago, so thought this the best place to ask.
The link given is for Google Apps, Google Maps still supports IE8 https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm not able to reproduce the issue on IE8 on XP SP3; all the maps I've tried load and refresh with no problem. Have you heard of anyone else encountering this problem? I'm curious if there's some corporate policy or plugin that could be the underlying cause.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for taking a look. The more I look at this the stranger it gets.

We managed to get a laptop with XP that is not on our network and it worked fine so it's only on PCs on our network. Also found that it works when XP is in safe mode, but having real difficulty in finding the cause of this.

The users said it was working last week, so uninstalled the latest Windows updates,but that didn't help. Most things found searching for this suggest Java,but we're not using that,but uninstalled anyway and no change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript memory leak on page refresh; remedy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990484/javascript-memory-leak-on-page-refresh-remedy)