# Does window.location.reload(true) affect javascript objects held in Internet explorer memory

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks, page-refresh

I am working on a memory leak issue in the Internet explorer. This is a single paged application that is displayed on a large screen and refreshed every thirty minutes using javascript `window.location.reload();`. After every refresh the memory size keeps on increasing. I suspect cross page leak in the application.
More about it here.

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/541
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx 
[Javascript memory leak on page refresh; remedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990484/javascript-memory-leak-on-page-refresh-remedy)

But what I noticed was when I changed the code to `window.location.reload(true);` i.e hard refresh memory usage is normal and there is no memory leak.

Now my question is when I am using `window.location.reload()` is it that other than using the cached javascript, Internet explorer also keeps the leaked javascript objects from the previous page in the Internet explorer memory while when  I am using `window.location.reload(true)` it not only gets fresh copies of the javascript files but clears any leaked objects held in the Internet explorer memory from the previous page. In short does hard refresh of a page affect the leaked objects held in Internet explorer memory related to that page.

Comment: Just judging from what you've posted, it seems like the hard refresh does affect the leaked objects. It seems like you've nearly answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)**:

> ***forcedReload Optional*** 
>   Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false
>   or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

When the page is forced to reload from the server, all page-specific objects in memory are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to destroy all page-specific resources in memory that include JavaScript objects you mentioned in question title. Its behavior is documented in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) as following:

> window.location.reload(forcedReload);
>
> ***forcedReload*** Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the
> page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not
> specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

but, IE 9 may have problems with such behavior as questioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache).